# Calling named function from other named function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function

I have run into a problem with a named function in Javascript.

I have this reload function

```
   SN.Reload = function(settings) {

        var _timer = null;
        var $grid = null;

        var init = function () {

            $grid = $(settings.wrapperSelector);

            if (_timer > 0 || _timer != null)
                _timer = settings.timer;
            else
                _timer = 600000;

            window.setInterval(function () {

                LoadData();

            }, _timer);

        };

        var LoadData = function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/data.json',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: UpdateData,
                error: DataErrorHandler
            });

        };
}
```

In the normal state this will run LoadData function at X minutes - this works as intended.

I now have another named function

```
SN.CreateJsonFromDate = function (settings) {

 .... 

  var SuccessLoad = function () {

        _dateLoader.hide();
        _wrapper.slideUp();



    }
}
```

Is it possible to use LoadData from SN.Reload Inside the SuccessLoad function in SN.CreateJsonFromDate ?

The LoadData function call UpdateData on success an updates the HTML from the json data and I want to call this function again in SN.CreateJsonFromDate as this will generate a new json file.

Comment: Looks like a private function.

Comment: Hang on...can I clarify that the intent of `SN.Reload` is to declare some variables (some of which are functions) and then do nothing with them and abandon them?

Comment: @Katana314 - yes you can clarify that, but it makes no difference. `LoadData` is only accessible inside the scope of `SN.Reload` and, as the code is written, is not accessible outside of it.

Comment: @Adam I kinda just assumed Reload was used for a primary purpose, and OP wanted to now use it for a secondary purpose. As the code example is written right now, it does not even have a primary purpose as it is never ever called and some minifiers would simply drop the functions entirely; I was implying he may have left out important code. The situation would change if, for instance, he had left out code that *did* make it accessible from the outside in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because simply `LoadData` does not exist outside the scope of `SN.Reload`

If you do want to re-use the `LoadData` function, do not restrict it's scope to being inside `SN.Reload` and instead, perhaps (depending on what you want), attach it to the namespace as `SN.LoadData`

Comment: Yeah.. The problem was the scope! Rewrote the entire script to make the reload function accessible and it is working now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you instantiate `SN.Reload`.
for example:

```
var obj = new SN.Reload(settings);
```

then you can use `LoadData` from this object, like this:

```
obj.LoadData();
```

And yes you have to make LoadData public using this:

```
this.LoadData = function(){/*your code*/}
```