# Calling function nested in other function with callback

Tags: javascript, function, object, callback

I have such structure:

```
var obj = {
   first: function(callback)
   {
      /* some code */

      var foo = function()  // i want to invoke this by callback
      {
        /* some code*/
      };

      if (callback) callback();         
   },

   second: function()
   {  
     /* some code */

     var bar = function()
     {
        /*some code */
     };
     bar();

     obj.first.foo();  // i want to invoke foo(), when bar() finishes it's job
   }
}
obj.first();
obj.second();
```

When I have tried to invoke `foo()` by callback i got **Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined**

I have problems with understanding JavaScript scope. How to invoke inner function nested in outer function, when I am in completely other function?

Comment: You can't. It's an inner function.

Comment: This is because `foo` is not defined until `first` has been invoked. By simply accessing the `first` prop, `foo` isn't defined. If you call `first`, then call `foo`, it should work. Edit: actually on second thought, I don't think `foo`'s scope will allow it to be called outside of `first`

Comment: Oh, i forgot - i am invoking `first()` below whole `obj`. So it's not the problem, i think

Comment: is your callback second?

Comment: O'boy  -> https://jsfiddle.net/seytdacq/

Comment: `first()` is invoked way before i am trying to invoke `callback`

Comment: Sorry, why do want to try to call an function internal to another function? You can't do that any more than you can access a variable internal to another function. If you want to access a function from outside, then place it in a scope where it is accessible. Also, I don't understand the part of your question where you say "you want to invoke this by callback"--what callback? What do you mean by saying "I want to invoke `foo()` when `bar()` finishes its job, when you are not even calling `bar` from anywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling named function from other named function in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636020/calling-named-function-from-other-named-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @torazaburo, i meant something @adeneo showed in link above. I need to execute `foo()`, when `bar()` make some data, which `foo()` need to do some other things. And `foo()` need to be in `first()`, because it's Google API function, and there is Google Map object, so i cannot move `foo()` (which is to **reverse geolocation**) outside `first()` scope.

Answer (score -2):

You cant call a function that you are currently using.

You can try something like:

```
var obj = somefunction;

somefunction{...}
```

Comment: Recursion will only work in javascript if you are not currently in the same function.

Comment: Not *"being in the same function"* would sure defeat the entire process of recursion, wouldn't it

Comment: `var num = 0;
var obj = function(num) {
    num++;
    console.log(num);
    if (num < 10) obj(num);
}
obj(num);` You sure about that?

Comment: You maybe right i dont have that much experiance, i just know that i spent the better part of yesterday trying to do exactly this to no success. And as soon as i pulled it out of the function it worked as a charm.